# Getting exception when reading two lines of data from text file in C#

Tags: c#, file-read

Hello I am reading two line of data from text file in C#, and at the end of file I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I know this error is because of end of file, and object is being assigned null value. But i need to avoid this error.
My code is in below format:

```
try
{
    sting line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine().Trim()) != null)
    {
        //do something
        if ((line2 = file.ReadLine().Trim()) != null)
        //do something
    }
}
catch(exception e)
{
    console.write(e.Message);
}
```

At end of file, is where it goes in exception.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If file.ReadLine() doesn't return anything, you'll get a NullReferenceException (the one you're getting) when you call Trim()

Comment: Two things:  1.  Try to make an effort to format your code.  People will be more willing to help if they can read your code.  2.  Make sure the code you do provide can compile.  You have a number of mistakes in the code that won't compile.  For example:  using `sting` instead of `string`.  `console.write` should be capitalized:  `Console.Write`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the code is calling `Trim()` on the result of the `ReadLine()` before checking if the result is null.

From [How to: Read a Text File One Line at a Time (Visual C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time):

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{
    // Do something with line
}
```

Also note that it's generally best to avoid calling `ReadLine()` again within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ?. operator, like:

```
file.ReadLine()?.Trim()
```